# How do i fix this error message identifier expected?

Tags: java, sql

This is my code

```
     import com.cordys.cpc.bsf.busobject.BusObjectConfig;
     import com.cordys.cpc.bsf.busobject.BusObjectIterator;
     import com.cordys.cpc.bsf.busobject.QueryObject;



     public class Employee extends EmployeeBase
     {
     public Employee()
     {
          this((BusObjectConfig)null);
     }

    public Employee(BusObjectConfig config)
    {
    super(config);
    }

   public static BusObjectIterator<com.devilsWSAPP.Employee>getEmployeeDetailsByJoiningDate(java.util.Date()JoiningDate)
 {
   String queryText = "select * from Employee where joining_date =:joiningDate";
   QueryObject query = new QueryObject(queryText);
   query.addParamemeter("joiningDate","Employee.joiningDate",QueryObject.PARAM_DATE, joining_date);
   query.setResultClass(Employee.class);
    return query.getObjects();
}}
```

The error I got is and How do I fix this??

> Error during Java compilation:
> 'java/Source/com/devilsWSAPP/Employee.java:25: error: 
> expected
> public static BusObjectIterator<com.devilsWSAPP.Employee>
> getEmployeeDetailsByJoiningDate(java.util.Date()JoiningDate)
>
>                                                                                          1 error '. Using Classpath:

Comment: `public static BusObjectIterator<com.devilsWSAPP.Employee>getEmployeeDetailsByJoiningDate`
There is a space missing there

Comment: @JoseNuno No there isn't. It's just as valid without it (even if not conforming to most style guides). It does not explain the error.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

> `java.util.Date()JoiningDate`

I don't know what you think that does, but it's the problem; that isn't java.

Perhaps you meant to write `Date joiningDate`? It'd be legal. A mistake, as well - Date doesn't represent dates (yeah, it's a rather unfortunate name). It represents moments in time (and badly at that). You presumably want `java.util.Date joiningMoment`, or better yet either `java.time.Instant joiningMoment`, or `java.time.LocalDate joiningMoment`.

Comment: "*but it's the problem; that isn't java*", greatest thing i've ever heard